# Issue With PL/SQL Bind Variables

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Recently, I deployed an Oracle WareHouse Builder (OWB) mapping. In the scenario I'm working right now, this mapping (ETL process) needs to be fired up by a trigger after an Update statement takes place on the fact table (working with WriteBack values).

As the mapping is deployed to the target schema as a package, the trigger must call the main procedure that OWB creates for the package. At first I didn't knew how to accomplish this task, but SQL Developer gave me a hint:

[image]

So, I took this code and put it inside my trigger. Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RESPALDO_HISTORIAL
AFTER UPDATE ON MONITOR_FT_TAB
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

  P_STATUS VARCHAR2(200);
  P_MAX_NO_OF_ERRORS VARCHAR2(200);
  P_COMMIT_FREQUENCY VARCHAR2(200);
  P_OPERATING_MODE VARCHAR2(200);
  P_BULK_SIZE VARCHAR2(200);
  P_AUDIT_LEVEL VARCHAR2(200);
  P_PURGE_GROUP VARCHAR2(200);
  P_JOB_AUDIT VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN

  P_MAX_NO_OF_ERRORS := NULL;
  P_COMMIT_FREQUENCY := NULL;
  P_OPERATING_MODE := NULL;
  P_BULK_SIZE := NULL;
  P_AUDIT_LEVEL := NULL;
  P_PURGE_GROUP := NULL;
  P_JOB_AUDIT := 'TRUE';

  SINIESTROS_MARCADOS_MAP.MAIN(
    P_STATUS => P_STATUS,
    P_MAX_NO_OF_ERRORS => P_MAX_NO_OF_ERRORS,
    P_COMMIT_FREQUENCY => P_COMMIT_FREQUENCY,
    P_OPERATING_MODE => P_OPERATING_MODE,
    P_BULK_SIZE => P_BULK_SIZE,
    P_AUDIT_LEVEL => P_AUDIT_LEVEL,
    P_PURGE_GROUP => P_PURGE_GROUP,
    P_JOB_AUDIT => P_JOB_AUDIT
  );

  :P_STATUS := P_STATUS;

END RESPALDO_HISTORIAL;
/
```

When I tried to compile this trigger, I got this screen:

[image]

In this screen I tried clicking "Aplicar" (Apply in spanish) with and without the NULL checkbox, always getting this output:

```
TRIGGER RESPALDO_HISTORIAL compilado
Errors: check compiler log
```

Then I ran the SHOW ERRORS command and I got this:

```
33/3           PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'P_STATUS'
```

Now I don't quite understand these bind variables. If this is the code generated by SQL Developer to run the package, then why I get this error??

Please help! I need some guidelines in this matter!
Greetings!

Answer (score 1):

A colon preceding a variable indicates that that variable is a bind variable. Bind variables of this type are typically used to pass values in and out of anonymous blocks. They're not allowed in procedures, functions, or triggers. In this case, you need to remove the line `:P_STATUS := P_STATUS;`.

Comment: But if I do this, how can I be sure that the ETL will execute correctly? I mean, remember I didn't wrote this code. It was generated by SQL Developer. Isn't this the exact same code OWB runs when executing the ETL from it?

Comment: I don't know what exactly your package does or why you're putting the call to it in a trigger. I answered the specific question you asked. If you need to know something further, either revise your question or post a new one. But, be specific. "How can I be sure this will execute correctly?" is too broad to receive a helpful answer.